# how to set passwordless authentication in a cluster where users /home directory from headnode is mounted to all machines /home of the cluster

Tags: nfs, cluster

First of all thank you in advance for your help.

I hope the title makes sense. Basically, on the headnode the users' home directory (i.e: headnode:/home/eric) are NFS shared and mounted to all the machines /home directory (i.e: node01:/home/eric)
I am trying to setup password-less SSH connections between all the users on the headnode and all the machines in the cluster. This is what I have done so far but i don't seem to be able to make it work.

I am running CentOS 7 on the headnode and all the machines in the cluster.

Mounted  headnode's /home to all machine's /home in the cluster. On the headnode the /etc/exports looks like this.

```
/home    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

On the headnode for user eric I generated the RSA key.

```
eric@headnode $: ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

With no passphrase.

Then I added the public key to the list of keys allowed to log in to eric's account.

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

I also created a "config" file in /home/eric/.ssh with the following lines.

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

I also edited /etc/ssh/ssh_config to reflect

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

I made sure that the /home/eric/id_rsa.pub key and the /home/eric/authorized_keys on the headnode are the same in /home/eric/id_rsa.pub key and the /home/eric/authorized_keys  on the machines in the cluster.
Which they are the same since /home/eric on the headnode is mounted on /home/eric in all machines in the cluster.

I also made sure that that the permissions on /home/eric/.ssh on the headnode and the machines in the cluster and the files inside .ssh were appropriate.

```
~/.ssh/  700
~/.ssh/authorized_keys  600
~/.ssh/config   600
~/.ssh/id_rsa  600
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 644
```

After all these steps I still cannot establish a password-less ssh connection between the headnode and the machines in the cluster.

Here is the verbose log when I ssh from the headnode to the node in the cluster.

```
    OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/eric/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to tq3 [10.112.0.14] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to tq3:22 as 'eric'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:M8Z5sDopU8J8sEkr9dkAwnIUbhcnLSKZjLfn5RykKA0
Warning: Permanently added 'tq3,10.112.0.14' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Did i miss or miss-configured something?

Thank you all for your help.

Eric

Comment: You wrote "Here is the verbose log", but I don't see any.

Comment: Are the NFS-shares mounted eager? /home/<user>/.ssh must exist prior to login. And why aren't you setting up the users on headnode followed by ssh-copy-id targeting the other nodes? Users also need to exist in /etc/passwd so that a user name can be mapped to a uid and also groups are assigned. Unless you use something like LDAP and manage identities elsewhere. Hopefully cluster nodes have their own host keys (/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key) and aren't full clones.

Comment: Bodo - I edited the body of my question with the verbose log.

motzman - /home/<user>/.ssh exists. Users exist in /etc/passwd on nodes with the same uid and groups as well as on the headnode with the same uid and groups. First I did ran  ssh-copy-id the users on the headnode targeting the other nodes but I could not ssh on the nodes without password. The nodes are not full cloned. I built the nodes one by one. However, I checked the /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key on the headnode and they are the same as on the nodes. I am not a ssh expert but is that ok ?

Comment: FYI:  I stopped the ssh daemon on a compute node, and ran "sshd" with some debug flags. I went on the headnode and I was able ssh into the compute node without a password.  The compute node's output is quite long but i could not see any error that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a SSH password-less connection from headnode to all compute nodes.

1. Make sure the user's `/hone/user/.ssh` is there. If not create the `.ssh` directory by running the following command:

   ```
   ssh-keygen
   ```
2. The `.ssh` directory might be there but the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` might not be there - to create the `id_rsa` and id_rsa.pub keys run the command

   ```
   ssh-keygen
   ```

   make sure to hit enter for blank password. If the SSH connection between headnode and the compute nodes is password protected, the SSH connection will fail.
3. Export the public key to the target host

   ```
   ssh-copy-id user@node_in_your_cluster
   ```
4. Test the the SSH password-less connection

   ```
   ssh user@node_in_your_cluster
   ```
5. Test the ssh password-less connection with the other compute nodes. The prompt will ask you to accept the connection

Comment: It looks like you have an answer in there, but it's very unclear. You're saying in step 1 that user has to run `ssh-keygen` to create /home/$USER/.ssh -directory, then run `ssh-keygen` again to obtain id_rsa and id_rsa.pub (obtain from where? Do you mean create?). in step 2 user needs to run `ssh-keygen` to create public key. What's the reason user should leave a blank password? Do ssh keys fail if they're password-protected? What's the purpose of step 3? The numerous typos do not help. Please see the advice on writing [a good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).